# What's ANT version to run Java 6 projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar, java-8

I have many legacy java 6 projects and I need to build it.

Using Eclipse Neon Ant plugin with Java 8 is building the **jar**, but  when I use the generated jar with another Java 6 project, I have the problem 'Unsupported major.minor version 52.0'.

My solution is install Ant version compatible with Java 6 and build the project out of Eclipse.

Comment: It is not an ant-version problem. You have to configure ant that it is used the correct jdk-version

Comment: have a look in to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi

Comment: What is the stack trace exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what version of Ant you use or what version of Java it was compiled with.

What matters is the JDK that the Ant `javac` task uses and the values of the `source` and `target` arguments of the javac task.

When running Ant from Eclipse you can set the JDK used in the 'JRE' tab of the 'Ant Build' you are using in the 'Run > External Tools Configuration' dialog. Choose a Java 6 JDK.

Specify `source="1.6" target="1.6"` on the `javac` task in your Ant build.xml.

Comment: wrong! Ant 1.10.x requires java 1.8 or higher.

Comment: ulab, you are correct. Downvoting this answer. Ant 1.9 runs on Java 6. Ant 1.10 requires Java 8.

Comment: @TheImpaler The question is about what version of Ant you need to run the 'javac' task at different compiler compliance levels - not about what version of Java Ant itself needs to run.

Comment: @greg449 OK, I got it wrong. You are right about compiling.